# Deletion safe way to store partial hash set copy in a sorted set

Tags: sorting, data-structures, redis, hashset, sortedset

I have read Redis documentation and everything but can't wrap my head around this use case.

I have the following data structure

```
=> title

=> content

=> date

=> score

=> id
```

And need to store just `title` and `date` in a sorted set which I do on every main post creation.

The problem lies when I have to delete that content on sorted set too, because if I do

`zadd 10 [title, date]` where `10` is the `score`, if then I want to delete it if there is another post with `score` `10` both will get deleted, which is not the functionality I want, and obviously so.

I've thought about prepending the post `id` to the score like `6+10` => `610` but it will screw up the set ordering and make a huge mess. Appending it is even more cumbersome, unmaintainable not to say very inefficient.

As a final note, I'm using sorted sets because I have 360.000.000+ items stored and a other sets will fail when I have to access an item in the middle.

How do I solve this (*deletion safe storing partial hash set copy in a sorted set*)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a lua script. As redis is monothreaded, when lua is executed, no other queries are executed concurrently (pessimistic locking).

In your lua script (EVAL command), you store the elements at the score you want to add (10 in your exemple with ZRANGEBYSCORE). Remove all elements at this score from redis with ZREMRANGEBYSCORE. Add back the stored elements in lua with ZADD in redis.

You use lua runtime as a memory buffer for your treatment. It should work pretty well as it is transactionnal.